# Proving $(A \land B) \to C$ and $A \to (B \to C)$ are equivalent

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus

> Prove that $(A \land B) \rightarrow C$ is equivalent to $A \rightarrow (B \rightarrow C)$ in two ways: by semantics and syntax.

Can somebody give hints or answer to solve it?

Comment: There are parantheses missing in $A\rightarrow B\rightarrow C$.

Answer (score 5):

Semantically it is easy. You can do a truth-table, and need to show the two wffs agree in truth-value for every valuation of $A$, $B$ and $C$.

Syntactically it will depend on the proof system you are being asked to use. But in a natural deduction system:

> Take $A \land B \to C$ as a premiss. Suppose (temporary assumption) $A$. Now suppose (temporary assumption) $B$. Those two assumptions give you $A\ \land B$. Modus ponens using the original premiss gives you $C$. Now you need to discharge the two assumptions in turn to derive first $B \to C$ (with $A$ still assumed), and then $A \to (B \to C)$ (on no assumptions beyond the original premiss).
>
> Take $A \to (B \to C)$ as a premiss. Suppose (temporary assumption) $A \land B$. Extract the conjuncts and two applications of modus ponens using the original premiss gives you $C$. Now you need to discharge the assumptions to derive  $A \land B \to C$.

Your task is now to write up those proof-sketches according to your favourite way of laying out ND proofs (Fitch-style or Gentzen-style).

[PS If you are being forced to use an axiomatic Hilbert-style system, complain bitterly to your instructor. If your syntactic system is a tree-system as in my book then you first assume $A \to (B \to C)$ and $\neg(A \land B \to C)$ and get your tree to close (just automatic) and then ...well, you should know how the story goes!]

Comment: @GitGud Thanks. Corrected.

Comment: I don't understand the remark about complaining bitterly about using an axiomatic Hilbert-style system.  If you only knew of natural deductive systems, then it probably would look like the deduction theorem would hold for all propositional logical systems, when it doesn't.  Also, from what I've read, though I have no definitive knowledge here, axiomatic Hilbert-style systems make it easier to do meta-theory.  There exist different questions also, since the independence of axioms is  meaningless in a natural deductive framework, but does have meaningfulness for axiomatic Hilbert-style systems.

Comment: I took the question to be from a beginner: and the remark was really about teaching Hilbert systems to beginners. Sure, further down the road, axiomatic systems are worth studying.

Answer (score 3):

Here is a third (also syntactic) way, to supplement Peter's two good solutions.

$$(A\wedge B)\to C$$
$$\neg(A \wedge B) \vee C$$
$$(\neg A \vee \neg B) \vee C$$
$$\neg A \vee (\neg B \vee C)$$
$$\neg A \vee (B\to C)$$
$$A\to (B\to C)$$

Comment: Does the system you're using have a definition that Cpq and ANpq mean the same thing, or do you have the logical equivalence ECpqANpq as an axiom or prove it as a theorem in that system?

Answer (score 0):

Semantically you can just consider two cases.  1) Suppose A is true, and 2) Suppose A is false.  Since all atomic propositions in classical logic are either true or false, but not both, this method will work.

Syntactically, we'll need to know the proof system (the axioms and the rules of inference for your system) to know how to solve this.

Comment: Why the down-vote here?